# Include file in jquery/Javascript without ID and Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(function(){
  $("#includedContent").load("header.php"); 
});
```

This function will include file but in a "DIV". I don't want to include file in DIV coz I am going to include in head section. Is there a way to include file on location where I place my SCRIPT instead of where I place DIV (by adding ID/Class use in script)?